# Can I send any character by get method in php?

Tags: php, get

I m building a small search script for my website. I need to send data by get method because by POST it will get real messy as I have to show many pages of search results.

So, My question is Can I use get method directly? means do i need to encode url or any other thing ??
I have checked it in modern browsers. It works just fine..

Thanks

Edit:
Urlencode is used when puting variables in url.

I am submitting my search form with method='get' Then I get variable and perform search query and make new page links with variable data.
- Length,Size is not a prob.
U people suggesting I should use urlencode func. while making new links only ???

Comment: HTTP GET is limited to 2KiBytes length

Comment: @stillstanding - Technically, GET isn't the limit but the browser in question is - ie6 barfs at URLs over 1024 chars - If I remember correctly, ie7 supported up to 4k. Apache can handle almost anything. That said, if you're getting anywhere close to that data length, you probably need to think about changing your approach - That's not what GET was intended for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can and should use urlencode() on data that possibly contains spaces and other URL-unfriendly characters.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I'd argue that you should use it irrespective of what you expect in the variable - there's onlyt a small overhead and it can prevent things breaking when you change code in future - but I completely agree

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL Encode the parameters on the URL eg `http://www.example.com/MyScript.php?MyVariable=%3FSome%20thing%3F`.

Be aware that there's a limit to how much data can be sent via `GET` - more restrictive on older browsers. If I remember correctly, IE6 has a limit of 1024 characters in the URL so if you think you're going to go over that, consider using `POST` or you may exclude some users.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `urlencode($variable)` ([Link](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)) before sending the variable (even though the browser usually takes care of this) and `urldecode ($variable)` ([Link](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)) after receiving it, this way you can be sure special chars will be treated correctly.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong as I haven't used PHP in a while but if I remember correctly, PHP handles URL Decoding for you when it exposes the parameters through the `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables...

Comment: I think so too. Coz I am not getting any problem while handling my complex search algorithm. I m just curious about if older browser do something stupid while sending form OR just break the new url of page the form is submitted to.